# Binary search must return a value, though a value is returned

Tags: java, recursion, binary, return, binary-search

I've been tasked with creating a binary search in Java using recursion. However, even though I specify return values, it is still telling me I must return an int result. Here are relevant parts of my code:

I've tried adding a return outside of the if-else statements, only to receive a StackOverflowError.

```
    result = binarySearch(numbers, 0, numbers.length-1, search);

    if(result==-1)
        System.out.println("Value not found.");
    else
        System.out.println(search + " was found at index " + result);

}

public static int binarySearch(int n[], int f, int l, int val) {        
    if(f>l) 
        return -1;
    else {
        int mid = (f+l)/2;
        if(val == mid)
            return n[mid];

        else {
            if(val < mid)
                binarySearch(n, f, mid-1, val);
            if(val > mid)
                binarySearch(n, f, mid+1, val);
        }

    }
}
```

I expected as follows: a value *search* is collected from the user and passed into the binarySearch method. The binarySearch method should then search my int array *numbers* from a starting value of 0 to the final value to find this value. In the binarySearch method, I believe that my logic is correct. When the initial low value is greater than the initial high value, that means that the search has completed and no result was found, so return -1. Otherwise, the item is in the array, so create a value *mid* to set the middle for the search. If the value being searched for is equal to middle, return the index that it was found at. If the value is less than the middle, then reduce the high value and run the search again, as the number must be to the left of the middle. If the value is greater than the middle, increase it and rerun as it must be to the right. Am I correct with my understanding of this? Why is it not recognizing the return inside the if-else statements?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You're not actually `return`ing anything in the recursive case.  Only running.  Voting to close as off-topic as your issue is down to a typo.

Comment: @JoeC Apologies, but has it occurred to you that not everybody holds the same level of understanding as you may? Things that might seem obvious to you may not be obvious to others. I'm not looking for handouts on the answer, I think that it is rather clear that I would like a proper explanation so I can understand and improve. I took the time to write down my logical thought process through my code so that I could be corrected if I was wrong.

Comment: Besides missing `return` you compare the middle index with the value you are searching for instead of the value in the middle index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is correct, you will just need to return after the recursion is complete along with replacing the two of comparing `val` and `mid` by if/else. The modified recursive function would be like this:

```
public static int binarySearch(int n[], int f, int l, int val) {
    if(f>l){
        return -1;
    } else {
        int mid = (f+l)/2;
        if(val == mid) {
            return n[mid];
        } else {
            if(val < mid) {
                return binarySearch(n, f, mid-1, val);
            } else {
                return binarySearch(n, mid+1, l, val);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This still returns me the same error, that I must return something of type int.

Comment: I've edited the response with the right code to remove the compilation error

Comment: I'm now being returned a StackOverflowError from the final line in the method:`return binarySearch(n, f, mid+1, val);`. This is a fault with recursion, is it not? I really am unable to locate my error.

Comment: Yes, this is a problem in the recursion logic itself. Specifically, in the second call of binary search, it should be `return binarySearch(n, mid+1, l, val);`. I have edited the code to reflect it.

Answer (score 0):

Compare val with n[mid], not mid.